# The userform won`t open

Tags: excel, vba, userform

The Error Says

> Run-time error 13 Type Mismatch

Every time I add this to user form. Any ideas why?

I've set it up as a module then called it in to the `UserForm_Initialize` then it shows an error and won't open the Userform
I am trying to add headers & controls to the `Listbox` Quote Details List

```
Sub Fill_Quote_Detail()

Dim QDetails As ListBox
Set QDetails = Body_And_Vehicle_Type_Form.Quote_Details

With QDetails

    Dim ws       As Worksheet
    Dim RngData  As Range
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Quote Detail")
    Set RngData = ws.Range("A1:K" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    QDetails.ColumnHeads = True
    QDetails.ColumnCount = RngData.Columns.Count
    
    Set RngData = RngData.Resize(RngData.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    QDetails.RowSource = RngData / Parent.Name & "!" & RngData.Address
    
    QDetails.ColumnWidths = "90;60;100;150;90;80;100;95;60"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Check the `Initialize` (and `Activate`) events of your form. The error is most likely there. If  you're working with forms/classes, you should set the error handling in the VBE to 'Break in class module'.

Comment: If Quote_Details is a listbox on the userform QDetails should be declared as MSForms.Listbox.

Comment: Also, if this is in the form, maybe `=Me.Quote_Details`

Comment: This `QDetails.RowSource = RngData / Parent.Name & "!" & RngData.Address` should result with an error, try QDetails.RowSource = RngData.Parent.Name & "!" & RngData.Address

Comment: This code is in a separate Module. I`ve tried to declare is as MSForms but the Set QDetails goes yellow.

Comment: The last massage code I have tried and I think it's right. I think it would work if I knew why this piece of code goes yellow. Set QDetails = Body_And_Vehicle_Type_Form.Quote_Details.

Answer (score 1):

Set your .RowSource using the following syntax:

```
.RowSource = RngData.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal)
```

After cleaning and sorting your code, try the modified code below:

***Modified Code***

```
Sub Fill_Quote_Detail()


Dim QDetails As MSForms.ListBox
Dim ws       As Worksheet
Dim RngData  As Range

Set QDetails = Body_And_Vehicle_Type_Form.Quote_Details

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote Detail")
With ws
    Set RngData = .Range("A1:K" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With

With QDetails
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = RngData.Columns.Count
    
    Set RngData = RngData.Resize(RngData.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' remove Header row
    .RowSource = RngData.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal) ' set your List-Box Source
    
    .ColumnWidths = "90;60;100;150;90;80;100;95;60"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @user14435479 you're welcome. Please mark as answer if it helped you solve your error

Answer (score 0):

The code should probably be in the Initialize event of the userform.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws       As Worksheet
Dim RngData  As Range
  
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Quote Detail")
    Set RngData = ws.Range("A1:K" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set RngData = RngData.Resize(RngData.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    With Me.Quote_Details

        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = RngData.Columns.Count
 
        .RowSource = RngData.Address(External:=True)
  
        .ColumnWidths = "90;60;100;150;90;80;100;95;60"
  
  End With

End Sub
```

Now all you need in Fill_Quote_Detail is one line.

```
Sub Fill_Quote_Detail()
    Body_And_Vehicle_Type_Form.Show
End Sub
```